# How to make this Samba share accessible without any user/password login?

Tags: password, samba, smb, shared-folders

I have modified `/etc/samba/smb.conf` to create a `[public]` share:

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
logging = file
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
server role = standalone server
obey pam restrictions = yes
unix password sync = yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
pam password change = yes
map to guest = bad user
usershare allow guests = yes
[public]
comment = Public Storage
path = /home/share
valid users = @users
force group = users
create mask = 0660
directory mask = 0771
read only = no
```

and then I did:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/smbd restart
sudo smbpasswd -a pi  # enter a password here
```

Unfortunately, when I access this shared folder from Windows, I need to enter a user/password login (see screenshot below).

**Question: how to make this Samba share accessible without any user/password login?**

[image]

---

PS: I created/mounted the shared folder like this:

```
sudo mkdir /home/share
sudo chown -R root:users /home/share
sudo chmod -R ug=rwx,o=rx /home/share
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /home/share
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
netbios name = NAS
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
logging = file
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
server role = standalone server
obey pam restrictions = yes
unix password sync = yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
pam password change = yes
map to guest = bad user
usershare allow guests = yes
[public]
path = /home/share
public = yes
guest only = yes
writable = yes
force create mode = 0666
force directory mode = 0777
browseable = yes
```

creates a share without any user/password login.

You can access it in Windows with `\\NAS\public`.